# How to convert dynamic shell arguments into URI query?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've got the following shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PARAMS=( arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8 arg9 )
[ $# -lt ${#PARAMS[@]} ] && { echo "Usage: $0 ${PARAMS[@]}"; exit 1; }
DATA=$(printf "%s=%s&" ${PARAMS[@]} $@)
echo curl "http://example.com/api/?${DATA%?}"
```

which aims at taking *n*-number of parameters and associate them with values read from the arguments.

So when I run:

```
./curl_params.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I expect the format to be:

```
curl http://example.com/api/?arg1=1&arg2=2&arg3=3&arg4=4&arg5=5&arg6=6&arg7=7&arg8=8&arg9=9
```

but instead, I've got:

```
curl http://example.com/api/?arg1=arg2&arg3=arg4&arg5=arg6&arg7=arg8&arg9=1&2=3&4=5&6=7&8=9
```

I understand that I need to combine `${PARAMS[@]}` with `$@`, so the values are merged.

Is there any Bash syntax that I can use to transpose/map the argument names with corresponding values?

<sup>To clarify, the names of the arguments may change.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`paste`** + **`printf`** solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PARAMS=( arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8 arg9 )
[ $# -lt ${#PARAMS[@]} ] && { echo "Usage: $0 ${PARAMS[@]}"; exit 1; }
data=$(paste -sd'&' <(paste -d= <(printf "%s\n" "${PARAMS[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "$@")))
echo curl "http://example.com/api/?${data}"
```

---

Test:

```
./curl_params.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
curl http://example.com/api/?arg1=1&arg2=2&arg3=3&arg4=4&arg5=5&arg6=6&arg7=7&arg8=8&arg9=9
```

Answer (score 2):

I would store `$@` in an array, then iterate over the indices: consider this bash session:

```
$ set -- a b c d e f g h i
$ args=( "$@" )
$ params=( arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8 arg9 )
$ declare -p params args
declare -a params='([0]="arg1" [1]="arg2" [2]="arg3" [3]="arg4" [4]="arg5" [5]="arg6" [6]="arg7" [7]="arg8" [8]="arg9")'
declare -a args='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f" [6]="g" [7]="h" [8]="i")'
$ for ((i=0; i<$#; i++)); do echo "${params[i]}=${args[i]}"; done
arg1=a
arg2=b
arg3=c
arg4=d
arg5=e
arg6=f
arg7=g
arg8=h
arg9=i
$ for ((i=0; i<$#; i++)); do echo "${params[i]}=${args[i]}"; done | paste -s -d'&'
arg1=a&arg2=b&arg3=c&arg4=d&arg5=e&arg6=f&arg7=g&arg8=h&arg9=i
```

However, bash can't handle

```
data=$( for ((i=0; i<$#; i++)); do echo "${params[i]}=${args[i]}"; done | paste -s -d'&' )
```

Apparently bash can't handle all the parentheses properly: In a script I get this error:

```
bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

So you can use a different loop:

```
data=$(
    let i=0
    while [[ $i -lt $# ]]; do
        echo "${params[i]}=${args[i]}"
        let i++
    done | paste -s -d'&'
)
echo "$data"
```

Note, don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES, leave those as reserved by the shell.

---

If your PARAMS is always "arg" followed by a number, you don't need to store "$@" in an array, you can refer to them with an indirect variable:

```
data=$(
    let i=1                          # note, starts at 1
    while [[ $i -le $# ]]; do        # and uses "-le"
        echo "arg${i}=${!i}"         # with ${!i} to get the positional param
        let i++
    done | paste -s -d'&'
)
echo "$data"
```